# How do I group by arbitrary time ranges in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
    A   B   C          D       E
8813    0   0   13:40:00    20.0
11998   0   0   18:00:00    20.0
12978   0   0   09:30:00    60.0
17899   0   0   19:00:00    15.0
19931   0   0   16:00:00    30.0
```

I would like to get, for each pair (B, C), the average E using hours (D) in two ranges: 1. 10 to 17.30, and Range 2. 17.31 to 20.30.

Something like:

```
    A   B   C      Range    Mean
8813    0   0          1    25.0 (8813+19931)/2
11998   0   0          2    17.5 (11998+17899)/2
```

How do I group by arbitrary time ranges in pandas?

Comment: Make Pandas.datetime objects for the endpoints; compare `'D'` to the enpoints; use the comparison with groupby; aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a range column using np.where

```
df['range'] = np.where(df['D'].dt.hour.between(10, 17.30), 1,\
np.where(df['D'].dt.hour.between(17.31, 20.30), 2, np.nan))
```

And then groupby

```
df.groupby(['B', 'C','range'])['A', 'E'].mean().reset_index().\
.rename(columns = {'A': 'A_mean', 'E': 'E_mean'})

    B   C   range   A_mean  E_mean
0   0   0   1.0     14372.0 25.0
1   0   0   2.0     14948.5 17.5
```